# Deallocating std::list without going out of scope

Tags: c++, stdlist

In STL one of the ways to create a dynamically allocated array is to create a list. When lists go out of scope destructor for every element is called and the list is deleted. Is there a way to destroy list (and more importantly release the memory used) before list going out of scope, and if it's possible then what is the best way to do it? Will delete[] or list::clear() do the job?

Comment: `list::clear()` removes all items from the list.

Comment: the list itself however will not get destroyed by calling `clear`

Comment: array is pretty much different from a `list`

Comment: @drescherjm yes, but will it free the memory?

Comment: `delete` and `delete[]` only comes in pair with calling `new` somewhere before. If you don't do `new` yourself (like in case with `std::vector` and other STL collections), **don't** call `delete`

Comment: ***but will it free the memory?*** Depends on what memory you are talking about.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number but destroying the list itself is quite pointless anyway.

Comment: @K.A.Kusakov you should [edit] and show some code so we know what it's all about

Comment: @apple you're right but I don't really know how to call it. Mayby I should call it item container or something?

Comment: You may need to show some small example code.

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? Afaik `clear` is not guaranteed to actually free all memory, it removes elements from the list though

Comment: @Jabberwocky thats why I asked. "Is there a way to destroy list (...) before list going out of scope" is unclear

Comment: @drescherjm from what I understand all dynamically allocated objects are allocated on the heap. I use a function that creates new lists, does something with them, throws them away, then and calls itself recursively. The lists I use can get really big, so I have to dealocate memory from the heap before calling itself.

Comment: You can define the list in a limited scope; `{ list some_list; ... } recurse();`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I need to free memory because I will run out if it really soon if I dont. See my response to drescherjm.

Comment: if done right you (almost) never have to manually deallocate memory. For your actual issue it would really help if you showed some code. Note however, that this question has already an answer, so you might consider to open a new question with a [mcve]

Comment: @K.A.Kusakov -- *I need to free memory because I will run out if it really soon if I don't* -- You have no control over when memory is *actually* released back to the operating system, even if you issued a `delete[]` call.  That is the runtime's heap manager's job.  A smart heap manager would *not* simply deallocate the memory every time a `delete[]` is issued.  If you run out of memory, it is solely due to a less than optimal structuring of your program.  A heap manager, after using a call to `delete[]` will mark those spots as "available", so the next `new[]` call will take over those spots.

Comment: @K.A.Kusakov what are you storing in the list?

Comment: note that `std::list` is most likely the wrong container anyhow. For many usecases `std::vector` is superior

Comment: As a side note, the linked list is the most overrated data structure, and only rarely appropriate. As another side note, it's more likely that you can remedy your issues by restructuring the code than by manual lifetime management.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh, so that's how it works! Thank you for explaining it to me. This means that using clear will be enough for my purposes.

Comment: @K.A.Kusakov A good heap manager would work this way.  A poor one would be naive and either 1) Call out to the OS each time `new[]` and `delete[]` is called, making things slower, or 2) Miss those empty spots, thus actually doing what you are fearing, and that is running out of memory.  For the latter, it can happen if the heap is fragmented to the point where the empty spots are not large enough to fulfill the memory request, so that is a possibility, but unless you actually experience it, don't worry about it.

Comment: Is it a list of raw pointers, or a list of objects?  (Technically, raw pointers are objects too.  Distinguishing between raw pointer objects from non-raw pointer objects.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In STL one of the ways to create a dynamically allocated array is to create a list.

Linked lists and arrays are quite different data structures.

> Is there a way to destroy list (and more importantly release the memory used) before list going out of scope

You can erase all elements of `std::list`, or any other standard container (excluding `std::array`) using the `clear` member function. All standard containers except for `std::vector` and `std::basic_string` release the memory allocated for elements when they are erased in practice. You may achieve the same with vector and string using `shrink_to_fit` after clearing.

Alternatively, it may be a good idea to make the scope of the list smaller instead.

> Will delete[] ... do the job?

No. `delete[]` may be used only with pointers to first element of array created using an allocating new-expression. `std::list` is not a pointer created using an allocating new-expression. You may not use `delete[]` on a `std::list`.

Comment: So, this means that clear() will do the thing for me? I dont just need to delete list, I need to specifically release allocated memory.

Comment: Are the elements of the list pointers? If so, erasing/clearing them won't free the pointed-to memory.